# Clone a document mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I am trying to query a collection; get the result objects and then I want to clone a document and save it into the same collection.

```
scenario = ModelScenarios.objects(pk=scenario_id).clone()
obj = scenario.update(ScenarioName=data['ScenarioName'])
```

This just updates the existing document, but it doesn't clone and apply the new data? How to do this?

Comment: You forget about [save()](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html?highlight=save#mongoengine.Document.save)

Comment: When i do obj.save() it says `AttributeError: 'BaseQuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'`

Answer (score 11):

There is no `clone` method on MongoEngine documents. With your code, you cloned the `QuerySet` that allowed you to get the document, not the document itself.

You should first get the document using the `get` method on the `QuerySet`:

```
scenario = ModelScenarios.objects.get(pk=scenario_id)
```

and then make a copy of it, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10611902/1345985):

```
from copy import deepcopy
obj = deepcopy(scenario)
obj.id = None
obj.ScenarioName = data["ScenarioName"]
obj.save()
```